# Are there buses from the Sunshine Coast (Coolum / Maroochydore) to Brisbane airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, brisbane, queensland, sunshine-coast, bne

In about a week's time, I'll need to get from the Sunshine Coast down to Brisbane Airport. Since I don't have a car, I'm looking to use a bus / coach / train / combination of the above.

For most public transport in south east queensland, the [Translink Journey Planner](http://jp.translink.com.au/travel-information/journey-planner) is my go-to website. However, for this case, it seems to suggest a ~3 hour journey involving 2 buses and 2 trains, for about $35 on a go-card, which seems a bit excessive...

That leads me to ask - are there any non-Translink buses or coaches from the Sunshine coast (around Coolum or Maroochydore) to Brisbane Airport, which manage the journey in less than 3 hours / less than $35?

(Sadly it isn't possible to change my flight to leave from the Sunshine Coast Airport, handily located between Coolum and Maroochydore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several, and most run multiple services a day.  Most will stop along the way though - rather than being a direct service.

- [Henry's Airporter](http://henrys.com.au/henrysbris.html)
- [The Pickup Company](http://www.thepickupcompany.com.au/)
- [Sun Air](https://www.sunair.com.au/?aid=334)
- [Cooloola Connections](http://www.coolconnect.com.au/)

Prices and times vary, so it's best you have a look and choose the best for you and your group.